# dojo.dijit editor headline plugin

Tags: plugins, editor, dojo

i am searching for a way to have a headline button in the dojo dijit editor that wraps elements with html h2 tags. 
Is there such a thing? i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the FontChoice plugin's formatBlock command, which provides a drop down of various "styles" like subheading, etc. which basically just wraps text with different tags. The list can be customized.